# Error using - Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix, size, equals, subtraction

I got the following error while working with a `MATLAB` program:

`Error using - Matrix dimensions must agree`

I noticed that the sizes of the matrices I'm trying to subtract from each other were:

`firstMatrix --> 425x356`

`secondMatrix --> 426x356`

How can I make them of equal size and go ahead and do my subtraction process?

I tried `reshape`, but the number of elements here seem to have to be equal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrices have a different number of elements, so there's no point using `reshape` here (since it maintains the total number of elements). You'll have to discard one of the lines in the larger matrix before doing the subtraction:

For instance, you can discard the last line:

```
firstMatrix - secondMatrix(1:end - 1, :)
```

or discard the first line:

```
firstMatrix - secondMatrix(2:end, :)
```

Alternatively, you can pad the smaller matrix with default values (*e.g* `NaN` or zeroes), as suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think both answers are missing the key point. Blithely subtracting two arrays of different size forgets that those arrays are NOT just numbers. The numbers must mean something. Else, they are just meaningless.

As well, simply deleting a row from the beginning or end may well be wrong, or padding with zeros. Only you know what the numbers mean, and why those arrays are not the same size. So only you can decide what is the proper action.

It might be right to pad, delete, interpolate, do any of these things. Or you might realize there is a bug in your code that created these arrays.

Comment: Perhaps interpolation is better, and that is indeed up to the OP to decide. But it is important to note that obtaining two arrays like that is not necessarily a bug. For instance, if you're computing the directional gradient of an image along the y-axis, you're bound to miss one row. Hence, if your image processing algorithm requires you to subtract the result from the original image, you will face the exact issue in question.

Comment: @EitanT - Yes, but IF you were assuming that the result after a difference is the same size, then it is indeed a bug, a bug of thought. Your code will not run properly because the arrays are not conforming in size. This is as much a bug as any other kind of bug.

Comment: I agree with this answer. @Simplicity should check *why* those matrices are different and what the intent of the subtraction is!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a row in `firstMatrix`

So can try:

```
firstMatrix=[firstMatrix;zeros(1,356)];
```

This will add a row of zeros at end of `firstMatrix` making it of `426x356`